# MySQL Query - Result Table Name

Tags: php, mysql, database

When I query a mysql database in PHP, I can not figure out how to specify the table of the field in the result set.

For example, I would like to do the following:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$row["table.FIELD"];
```

But, can not figure out how. Surely, it is able to happen somehow.

**EDIT:** I have checked documentation, and have found nothing. I am not sure if I was understood at first... I know how to get the value of a field in a row from a result set. But, I would like to be able to get the value of a field in a row by specifying the name of the table in front of that field.

```
$row["FIELD"]; vs $row["table.FIELD"];
```

From the above line, I would like to do the latter.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get it as `$row[field_name]`,
And if you have two fields with same name but from different tables, You **must** add at least to one of them table.field AS somthing_else

```
SELECT t1.id,t2.id AS 't2_id' ....
...
...
var_dump($row);
```

will give `$row['id'],$row['t2_id']`

While if you **don't** use the `AS` you will get only `$row['id']` (one value was lost).

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely in $row['FIELD'], depending on how you structured your SQL statement.

Try print_r( $row ) to see everything that's in the array.

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation explains](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) how to do what you want, check the examples.

Comment: RTFM is rarely a good answer to a question this specific. The OP was asking if there is a native way to include table names in results in order to avoid collisions with names from joined tables. The answer is: there is regrettably no native way - use aliases.